# What is wrong in this bash read -n?

Tags: bash

I'm learning Bash and am looking at the read command. I thought the difference between the -N and the -n option was that -N would overwrite the IFS while -n wouldn't. In the following example I expected var6 to take the value of "ijfz", because I thought the space would act as field separator.
But it seems to have value "ijfz e". The space wasn't used as field separator

```
printf "%s\n" "ijfz eszev enacht" | {
read -n 6 var6
printf "%s\n" "$var6"
}
```

I wanted to see what was $IFS, but the following printf command doesn't learn me too much:

```
printf ":%s:\n" "$IFS"
```

gives the following output

```
:   
:
```

What am I not understanding...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By delimiter it means using option `-d`. See this difference:

```
printf "%s\n" "ijfz eszev enacht" | { read -d ' ' -N 6 var6; printf "[%s]\n" "$var6"; }
[ijfz e]

printf "%s\n" "ijfz eszev enacht" | { read -d ' ' -n 6 var6; printf "[%s]\n" "$var6"; }
[ijfz]
```

1. In first case when using `-N` it ignores `-d ' '` and reads **exactly 6 characters**.
2. In second case when using `-n` it respects `-d ' '` and reads **until a space is read**.